# NSDateFormatter return nil from specific dates

Tags: ios, null, nsdateformatter

I'm having trouble with `NSDateFormatter` that returns nil with specific dates like, October 16, 2016 | October 15, 2017 | October 21, 2018 ...

I try some date patterns: yyyy/MM/dd, MM/dd/yyyy, dd/MM/yyyy but always return nil.

Any idea?

Comment: Why do you try patterns including a slash although your dates don't contain any slash? Look at http://www.unicode.org/reports/tr35/tr35-31/tr35-dates.html#Date_Format_Patterns . Maybe there's a daylight saving change issue.

Comment: I wrote October 16, 2016 but I`m using 16/10/2016, anyway, if I use the pattern LLLL d, yyyy, return nil too.

Comment: Update your question with real, relevant code. Also include actual output from logging the actual values you are trying to parse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you living in Brazil?

On these 3 particular dates the Daylight Saving Time changes in Brazil from 0:00 to 1:00.

Since 0:00 does not exist the date is `nil`.

Comment: You`re right, I change the pattern to "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm" and use the date "16/10/2016 01:00" and works. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

If your date is getting as string.

```
NSString *dateStr = @"October 16, 2016";

   // Convert string to date object
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [dateFormat setDateFormat:@"LLLL d, yyyy "];
    //  [dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];

    NSLog(@"%@", [dateFormat stringFromDate:date]);
```

If you use `[dateFormat setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];` it will give the result as `10/16/16`

For **swift**
Use this format : `MMMM d, yyyy`

```
 var mydate = "October 16, 2016"
        let formatter = NSDateFormatter()
        formatter.locale = NSLocale(localeIdentifier: "en_US_POSIX")
        formatter.dateFormat = "MMMM dd, yyyy"
        if let parsedDateTimeString = formatter.dateFromString(mydate) {

            print(formatter.stringFromDate(parsedDateTimeString))
        } else {
            print("date format is wrong")
        }
```

**Output:**
October 16, 2016

Comment: Nop, returns nil too. I`m using Swift 2.

Comment: let dateFormatter = NSDateFormatter()
dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy"
var date = dateFormatter.dateFromString("16/10/2016")

date return nil.